# Copy Data from Azure Data Lake to SnowFlake without stage using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

All the Azure Data Factory examples of copying data from Azure Data Lake Gen 2 to SnowFlake use a storage account as stage. If the stage is not configured (as shown in picture), I get this error in Data Factory even when my source is a csv file in Azure data lake - "Direct copying data to Snowflake is only supported when source dataset is DelimitedText, Parquet, JSON with Azure Blob Storage or Amazon S3 linked service, for other dataset or linked service, please enable staging".
[image]

At the same time, SnowFlake documentation says the the external stage is optional. How can I copy data from Azure Data Lake to SnowFlake using Data Factory's Copy Data Activity without having an external storage account as stage?
If staging storage is needed to make it work, we shouldn't say that data copy from Data Lake to SnowFlake is supported. It works only when, Data Lake data is is first copied in a storage blob and then to SnowFlake.

Comment: Does it work if you configure the source as Azure Blob Storage instead of Azure Data Lake?  Data Lake supports both protocols.

Comment: Can you reference the "SnowFlake documentation says the the external stage is optional"? Does this documentation refer specifically to Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Does it work if you configure the source as Azure Blob Storage instead of Azure Data Lake? Yes, it works if the source is Azure Blob Storage but fails if we use Lake Gen 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though Snowflake supports blob storage, Data Lake storage Gen2, General purpose v1 & v2 storages,  [loading data into snowflake is supported- through blob storage only](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure.html).

> The source linked service is Azure Blob storage with shared access signature authentication. If you want to directly copy data from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 in the following supported format, you can ***create an Azure Blob linked service with SAS authentication against your ADLS Gen2 account***, to avoid using staged copy to Snowflake.

Select Azure blob storage in linked service, provide **SAS URI** details of `Azure data lake gen2` source file.

Blob storage linked service with data lake gen2 file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In that case, how do we make a stage Blob storage secure with SnowFlake Enterprise that doesn't support PrivateLink. My client doesn't want any publicly open storage account. Do we have any option? My client doesn't want to upgrade to SnowFlake Business Critical that suports PrivateLink.

Comment: Hope this [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-azure.html#configuring-secure-access-to-cloud-storage) helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to configure blob storage  and use it as staging. As an alternative you can use external stage. You'll have to create a FILE TYPE and NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION and access the ADLS and load data into Snowflake using copy command. Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: In that case, how do we make a Blob storage secure with SnowFlake ENterprise that doesn't support PrivateLink. My client doesn't want any publicly open storage account. Do we have any option?

Comment: With SAS authentication it is secure. In Linked Service you can pass the SAS token.

Comment: SAS token is used by Azure Storage to authorize access to the storage resource. this is not meeting network security requirements. storage account endpoint is still open to public

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Data factory Dataflow activity instead of copy activity and load to sink, although look for performance (cluster time to live) in integration runtime and partitioning types in source and sink based on the volume of data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).